# How to enable ssh on startup in opensuse

Tags: ssh, opensuse

My experience with Linux is limited and as part of a project, I ordered a Linux dedicated server. This is an unmanaged server with OpenSuSE 13.2. When I try to ssh into the server, I get a connection refused message

```
ssh: connect to host xxx.xxx... port 22: Connection refused
```

*I think their default image does not comes with ssh enabled on startup but I may be wrong*. They provide a rescue system which is a Linux system installed and loaded from ram for troubleshooting. When I load this, I can connect to the system via SSH. I can mount the hdd and make changes.

**I'd like to know how to check and/or whatever configuration changes that need to be done to enable ssh on startup for OpenSuSE 13.2 from within a *recovery system***. I can provide any configuration file contents if required. I'm basically from a Windows background and hence if you can provide verbose steps, it will be helpful.

As part of my research, I checked init.d file, there was no `sshd` file in there, ssh is installed I guess as there exists files in `/etc/ssh` like `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.

Comment: My question as specified by the title is not about the connection refused error.

Comment: This question is **not** asking what causes a connection refused message. It asks how to check which services are enabled on an OpenSuSE system, and how to change it. As such it should not have been closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 10):

**1. Verify installation**

Run `which sshd` to get the path it is called from. If you don't get `/usr/sbin/sshd` in response, it is most likely not installed.

**2. Installing sshd**

Run `zypper in openssh` to install the application.

**3. Check firewall**

Run the command `cat /etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2 | grep sshd`.

You need to see `FW_CONFIGURATIONS_EXT="sshd"` - This means the firewall allows incoming traffic on port 22.

If you do not find it, you may add it using a text editor like this:

`vi /etc/sysconfig/SuSEfirewall2` and locate the line where it says `FW_CONFIGURATIONS_EXT=""` and change it to `FW_CONFIGURATIONS_EXT="sshd"`

**4. Check the service is running**

`systemctl status sshd | grep Active` - If you get `Active: inactive (dead)` you need to start it with `systemctl start sshd`.

Run the command again `systemctl status sshd | grep Active` and you should now see `Active: active (running) since ...`

**5. Enable SSH on startup**

`systemctl enable sshd`

Comment: You are reading only part of the question. I sincerely appreciate your efforts, but the problem is, system while in running condition cannot be accessed because its a remote machine and only mode of access, the `ssh` is not running, but I can access the hard disk, I needed to get configuration changes to be done on the files in this HDD, from an external OS, so that next time OS is booted from this hard disk, `ssh` will be running. My actual requirement is no more active but if someone can answer, it might help someone else.

Comment: How were you accessing the system? If you were able to determine files exist in `/etc/ssh` you must have access of some kind. Was this through a cloud provider? Were you running it on a ESXi server on your own network? How did you access the disk through an external OS (I assume you mean from another host). Too bad I got to this question so late, because now I really want to solve it.

Comment: It is through a recovery system, another linux system booted up in memory much like a live cd. It is an provided by the hosting provider.

Answer (score 5):

OpenSUSE as of Leap 15, and Tumbleweed got rid of the old firewall in favor of [firewalld](/questions/tagged/firewalld) as used on Fedora. That changes how you add the SSH config:

```
firewall-cmd --add-service=ssh --zone=external --permanent
```

**--add-service=ssh** Since SSH is one of the predefined services, you can use it as a service. The alternate is `--add-port=22`.

**--zone=external** Updates the external zone. Zones are assigned to interfaces.

**--permanent** Persists this change across reboots.

To verfiy this is done, the XML files in `/etc/firewalld/zones` can be examined.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<zone>
  <short>External</short>
  <description>For use on external networks.</description>
  <interface name="eth0"/>
  <service name="ssh"/>
  <masquerade/>
</zone>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think I articulated the question wrong. Though not relevant anymore, the question basically was, I have remote access to a HDD with opensuse image (access is through a different linux OS), this HDD can be booted, but the opensuse on it don't have ssh enabled, so through the remote access to the HDD through a different linux OS, what changes to be made on the files in HDD itself, so that next time it is booted, SSH access is available on the opensuse system. So I cannot call commands inside opensuse, just edit files.